# Why can't I play audio on Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to play a mp3 on Android Studio when I play start icon but I am getting below error:

```
invalid attributes { Content type: AUDIO_CONTENT_TYPE_UNKNOWN Usage: AUDIO_USAGE_UNKNOWN Source: -1 Flags: 0x800 Tags:  } when converting to stream
```

The same code was working fine the last time while I running the code but this time I got this error. My source code is :

```
    @Composable
fun BreathePage() {
    val currentContext = LocalContext.current
    val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(currentContext, R.raw.watersound)

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.waveywater),
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds)
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {

        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            IconButton(onClick = {
                mediaPlayer.start()
            }) {
                Icon(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.playicon), contentDescription = null)
            }
            IconButton(onClick = {
                mediaPlayer.pause()
            }) {
                Icon(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.pauseicon), contentDescription = null)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Android Studio is an IDE, not a media player. Did you mean "Why can't I play audio in my Android app"?

Comment: Yes I mean when I click a button on my Android App the mp3 is not playing. Of course I am not trying to listen to music with an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a resourceID. Try this:

```
var resID = context?.resources?.getIdentifier("YOUR_FILE_NAME", "raw", context.packageName)

resID?.let {
    // No file found when it == 0
    if (it == 0) {
        val errorString = "Error has occured"
        //handle error
        return
    }
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, it)
    mediaPlayer?.start()
    return
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this didn't work for me.